# Buscar Índice da matriz a partir do valor do json usando o indexOf

Tags: javascript, json, array, matriz, indexof

Tenho a seguinte matriz:

```
var usuarios = [
    {nome: "João", id: 1},
    {nome: "Maria", id: 2},
    {nome: "José", id: 3},
    {nome: "Ana", id: 4},
];
```

Preciso retornar o índice do usuário José.
Tentei usando o indexOf da seguinte forma:

```js
var usuarios = [
        {nome: "João", id: 1},
        {nome: "Maria", id: 2},
        {nome: "José", id: 3},
        {nome: "Ana", id: 4},
    ];
  
  console.log(usuarios.indexOf({nome: "José", id: 3}))
```

Porém é me retornado -1. Sei que é possível fazer isso com o for(), mas é possível fazer com o indexOf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tua lógica falha porque objetos são únicos, a não ser que sejam referência um do outro.

Repara nestes exemplos:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
console.log(a == b); // false

var a = {};
var b = a;
console.log(a == b); // true
```

Portanto quando usas o `indexOf` ele vai procurar na array por um elemento `==` e vai dar sempre false.

Podias fazer uma aproximação, mas que não é viável assim:

```
var u = usuarios.map(JSON.stringify);
console.log(u.indexOf('{"nome":"José","id":3}')); // dá 2
```

Mas nesse caso comparas strings e perde-se a vantagem de usar objetos. Como sugeriste o melhor é com ciclo for e com `break` ou `return` para não precisar de chegar ao fim, mas mesmo aí tens de comparar valores e não o objeto em si (a não ser como disse em cima que tens uma referência numa variável):

```
function getId(nome) {
    for (var i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++) {
        if (usuarios[i].nome == nome) return i;
    }
}

console.log(getId('José')); // dá 2
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dds3w9o8/

Comment: poderia usar também o `console.log(usuarios.map(o => o.nome).indexOf("José"))` assim como dentro da function, certo? https://codepen.io/flourigh/pen/NWPVVeY

Comment: @flourigh com JavaScript moderno podes fazer diretamente `usuarios.findIndex(o => o.nome === 'José');`

Comment: de fato, então porque preferiu o formato de sua resposta?

Comment: @flourigh porque a minha resposta tem quase 4 anos e na altura ainda não existia suporte para esse método, ele foi lançado com a versão ES6 de JavaScript.

Comment: poxa, agora que vi a data, tal pergunta apareceu no feed por ter a sua resposta editada, porque alguém edita uma resposta de 4 anos